# Update data from DialogFragment

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

I want to update name and email `onClick` holder in RecylerView1.

`onClick` a Dialog open with list of name and email in another RecylerView2 on click holder of RecyclerView2 update the holder of RecyclerView1

I implemented all thing except updating back data to RecylerView1 form ReyclerView2.

[See details in Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsndh.png)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using adapters in the recycle view to show the items then you can update the values in adapter data then call the method "notifyDataChanged" to update the layout. Or else if you have your project code then share it with us. Or share a GitHub link for the better explanation.

Comment: yes i am using ReyclerView adapter first i need data form recyclerview2 to notifyDataChanged recyclerview1

Comment: Pass the data in a bundle and after finishing the current view fragment just try to get this bundle as extras in the first activity. Or also you can make some variable static in the main Base activity so that after update change those static variable and then again get it from the base activity